# 1045 when connecting to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The error is 1045. But my username and password are correct.

I am connecting as fcapdi from 192.168.0.18 (to 192.168.0.240:3306)

My users table

```
 MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
 +--------+-----------+
 | User   | Host      |
 +--------+-----------+
 | dba    | %         |
 | fcapdi | %         |
 | root   | 127.0.0.1 |
 | root   | ::1       |
 |        | localhost |
 | root   | localhost |
 |        | tester    |
 | root   | tester    |
 +--------+-----------+
```

When I login with phpMyAdmin with the `root` account I receive

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

But my account dba can login fine. What is going on?

Also I guess I should note the MySQL instance is sitting on a server that has 2 NIC's and sits on 2 (internal) networks. One is a local domain `192.168.0/24` the other is a larger domain `10.228./16`.

I can login via the fcapdi account from the `10.228./16` network. But not from the `192.168.0./24` network.

Comment: determine how many root users you have. Reset all their passwords to the same thing

Comment: `select user,host,password from mysql.user` or `select user,host,authentication_string from mysql.user` ... eyeball the hashes

Comment: Okay quick question. When I have multiple root users who are on the same host, how do I change their passwords? I currently have `root@localhost`, `root@127.0.1.7`, `root@::1` and `root@tester` but then I have a `root@localhost, tester, 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Execute:

```
GRANT ALL ON 
    your_database_schema_name.* to 
    'fcapdi'@'192.168.0.18' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_connection_password';
```

as user with GRANT privileges on the server and try to connect.

Comment: It would seem he wants %

Comment: if %, it allows from any IP from which you connect. This is for security to specify particular IP address.

Comment: I need to connect from multiple hosts to this DB. fcapdi is an insert only account. It'll be on dozens of workstations. Also the `%` symbol should allow multiple IP address correct? Furthermore this doesn't explain why `root@localhost` would be denied login.

Comment: Alright. You can restrict the IPs from your subnet if you would like to by specifying '192.168.0.%' or '192.168.%', or % for any IP as you need.

Comment: But how does this solve the underlying problem of being reject from remote logins when I'm allowing logins from `%`? Also how does this solve the issues of `root@localhost` not being able to login?

Comment: It potentially resets a forgotten password

Comment: @Drew said, looks like the root password on localhost is not matching. You may reset it by following http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
As an aside question under comments

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newPass123^'); 
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('newPass123^'); 
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'etc_etc' = PASSWORD('newPass123^'); 

you can also do it in a single update statement but it depends on your mysql version

create user 'joe1'@'localhost' identified by 'blah';
create user 'joe1'@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'afadfafsdblah2';
create user 'joe1'@'%' identified by 'djdjdjjdjdd';;


select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='joe1';
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host      | password                                  |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| joe1 | localhost | *0380BEA27363E56C37F0BFDA438F429080848051 |
| joe1 | %         | *7BEAF25E9BDFBDEF5A9B9E4A37023721B668FA51 |
| joe1 | 127.0.0.1 | *5CD978E569B31B1558E5C1D0972E6E02516893BF |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+

update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('nEW_COMMon_password762') where user='joe1';
-- 3 rows updated

select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='joe1';
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host      | password                                  |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| joe1 | localhost | *A248B352CE5BF750A11AA9BA253B5F191C721D1A |
| joe1 | %         | *A248B352CE5BF750A11AA9BA253B5F191C721D1A |
| joe1 | 127.0.0.1 | *A248B352CE5BF750A11AA9BA253B5F191C721D1A |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

For Mysql 5.7 it is **not** a column named `password`. Instead do it against `authentication_string`

Cleanup:

```
drop user 'joe1'@'%';
drop user 'joe1'@'127.0.0.1';
drop user 'joe1'@'localhost';
```